# Joint Tracking using Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I am trying to track several joints at the same time using the Kinect SDK and C# sample of code from the Channel9.msdn website. I am following the same example code they have there, but I am unable to have one of my image representations move. The two ellipses I have that represent the hands are able to track my movements, but the headImage that represents the head joint automatically moves to the top left corner of the window and doesn't move. If i change the joint to be tracked to be another joint, such as one of the ones represented by the ellipses (which I know is tracking), the  headImage still goes to the top left corner of the window. How is it I can track the hand joints using the ellipses, which follow my movements, but the headImage image does not move no matter what joint I set it to?

Update: It seems that when I remove the image object from the .xaml window and replace it with another ellipse object, all the ellipses start moving, which means the ellipse representing the joint that did not move before, is moving and is able to track. It must be a problem with using that particular image object (it is the head image that is the same chosen for the Channel9.msdn tutorial).

Comment: so there is a problem or did you solved it ?

Comment: Well the problem I had was I couldn't get one of my images, which represented a joint to move. When i switched the image to something else (an ellipse image object) it worked (only because i use the same .xaml line of code from the other ellipse for this joint location.) Most likey i had forgotten to set a parameter, event, or property to allow it to work.

Comment: Problem solved by fixing the .xaml code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK v1.6 Toolkit examples, have a look at the SkeletonBasics project.  It shows you have to track the entire skeleton and draw each of the joints, along with connecting lines.  Just remove what you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I sugest look at the Toolkit examples mentioned by @Evil Closet Monkey and perhaps look to the examples provided with kinect.toolbox ([Kinect Toolbox page](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/)) the examples provided here, are too simple and good.